# How can I fill a Rectangle with a Hexadecimal color value?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, colors

```
'#10eeee'
```

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
groupRectangle.Fill = Color.FromHex?
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're looking for [ColorConverter.ConvertFromString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms606533.aspx).

```
Color color = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#10eeee");
SolidColorBrush myBrush = new SolidColorBrush(color);
```

You will need `using System.Windows.Media;` at the top of your program too.

The following [string Color formats should be supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.color.aspx).

**Edit:** You can also use [BrushConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.brushconverter.aspx).

Comment: Sounds like you want a brush not a colour. Try `new BrushConverter().ConvertFromString("#FFFFFF")`